# Turn array of jQuery.get results from array into string within console

Tags: jquery, arrays, google-chrome-extension, console

I'm having some trouble within the console. I'm using the following code that takes an array of URL's and get the source code from those URL's.

```
var URL = ["http://www.website.com", "http://www.anotherwebsite.com"];
var str = [];

$.each(URL, function(index, fetch) {
   $.get(fetch, function(sourcecode) {
     str.push(sourcecode); 
   })
 });

console.log(str);
```

This returns the following array within the console:

[image]

However, I need that array to turn into a **single** string of all the source code. I tried using **str.join** but that doesn't work. I need the console to look like this:

[image]

Maybe im just missing a simple piece of code, but I cannot get it to work.

Note: This is within a Google Chrome Extension so cross domain requests are not an issue.

Comment: I tried using that - doesn't work. It returns an empty array.

Comment: Are you sure `console.log(str);` outputs array as in image. Because `$.get` is asynchronous that value may push at any time

Comment: or `str = str + ` ...

Comment: There was just an answer posted on that. I've tried it before, but returns an empty line within the console. Not sure why it does that especially since it is a normal array before you try to change it into an string.

Answer (score 1):

[`$.get`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/) is not what you are looking for. "Due to browser security restrictions, most "Ajax" requests are subject to the same origin policy; the request can not successfully retrieve data from a different domain, subdomain, port, or protocol."

You want to use [`$.ajax`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) instead.

This is going to get you close:

```
var URL = ["http://www.google.com", "http://www.jquery.com"];
var str = "";

$.each(URL, function(index, fetch) {
    $.ajax({
      url: fetch,
      dataType: "jsonp",
      success: function (sourcecode) {
         str += sourcecode;
      }
    });
 });

console.log(str);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/0zueyx97/

But you are still going to have some errors:

> SyntaxError: expected expression, got '<'
>   SyntaxError: expected expression, got '<'

This is due to cross domain issues [See Here for solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30002244/2940627)

Comment: Unfortunately, I've tried that. It returns a blank line. I'm completely clueless as to why it does that.

Comment: Update: It does work if the console.log is written next to str += sourcecode. However, the result in the console is the string of the source code from both URL's, but within different lines, almost like an array. I can access the variable outside of the function, and it is not a single string with the combination of the source code.

Comment: I tried it, and it returns a blank line within the console. I placed the console.log within the function and nothing shows in the console. This code is within a Google Chrome extension, do cross site requests are not an issue.

Comment: Still brings up a blank line, almost as if the array won't turn into a single string. Cross domain requests won't be an issue as this is within a Google Chrome Extension.